# How do I export a table into Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I have a table where data gets populated dynamically and I would like to export this table as a ***.xlsm*** or ***.xls*** format using JavaScript. It should work in IE

This is my table:

```
function Table(x) {
var statusCol = "";
var table = '<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
var ID = 0;
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    var row = "<tr age='"+(12+i)+"' class='staff-row' id='" +"ColId"+i + "'>";

    row += '<td>' + "FName" + '</td>';
    row += '<td>' + "SName" + '</td>'
    row+="</tr>"
    ID++;
    table += row;
}
table += '</table>';
$('#DisplayTable').html(table);
$('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
    'show': true,
    'selector':'.staff-row',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': function(event){
        var $this=$(this);
        var tds=$this.find('td');            
        return $(tds[0]).text()+" "+$(tds[1]).text()+" age: "+$this.attr("age");
    },        
});

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default export">
```

I did a bit of online search and all I found was this, but I don't understand some of these code examples e.g. How do I link my table to this? and how would I embed this code so that when a user clicks on a button a ***.xlsm*** file gets exported. I mean I do have `onClick` function but it does nothing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.export').on('click', function () {
            var tableToExcel = (function () {
                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                  , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                  , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                  , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
                return function (table, name) {
                    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
                    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                }
            })()
        });
    });
```

Here is a JSFiddle:
<kbd>[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lks5L/6/)</kbd>

This is what other people have done <kbd>[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/537/)</kbd>
I have also looked at [Link](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: In the past i've used this plugin https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify. You can make a .csv easily which Excel will open happily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest export from tables to Excel is Jquery DataTables Table Tools plugin. You get a grid that sorts, filters, orders, and pages your data, and with just a few extra lines of code and two small files included, you get export to Excel, PDF, CSV, to clipboard and to the printer.

try this datatable link, 
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html